# How to deal with the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error when calling `insert_aligned_tablets` in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I installed Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.2, and my data is encapsulated by NumpyTablet. I used python API to call the `insert_aligned_tablets` function, and an error is reported: `Caused by: org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.WriteProcessException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Does anyone know what this error means and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem should be solved if you use Version 1.2 of Apache IoTDB, so you can try to upgrade your Version 1.1.2 IoTDB, and the data should be successfully written.